# Find ratio/algorithm to translate different coordinate systems?

Tags: algorithm, math

So I have two different coordinate systems, one is the incoming data and the other is how i plot points in the app. Is there a formula that, given some aligned up points, will give me an algorithm to calculate future points? Eg:

`X = 6.5 & Y = 2`  on one system is == `X = 3101 & Y = 3441` in the other system.

Another set is `6.45/2.37 = 3211/3414`. From these two matchups, how can I calculate a formula to "translate" one system into the other?

Comment: Assuming that the translation is linear, for X and Y separate you will have a set of equations with 2 unknowns. X2 = A*X1 + B, plug X1 (6.5) and X2 (3101) into the equation, as well as X1 (6.45) and X2 (3211) into it, and you can solve it to find A and B to find your linear equation, then do the same thing for Y.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; you may have better luck on [math.se].  Also, you'll probably need a third point (or does the origin stay fixed?).

Comment: If the translation is linear he has all he needs.

Comment: I just need to translate the 6.5/2 system into the 3xxx/3xxx system. @LasseV.Karlsen im not sure i understand your solution, plugging in those first values leaves me with `3101 = 6.5a + b`. I need to find the coordinates in the first system (the smaller numbers) from input such as `y = 3534,x = 2323`. Doesnt linear interpolation just give you a value of a percentage between two  similar points?

Comment: Which kinds of transformations are allowed between your two coordinate systems? Translation, scaling (uniform or non-uniform), rotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve two equations with two unknowns for X, and then the same for Y.

Let's go through this. First we do X:

```
3101 = 6.5  * a + b
3211 = 6.45 * a + b
```

First we isolate b:

```
3101 - 6.5  * a = b
3211 - 6.45 * a = b
```

Which gives:

```
3101 - 6.5 * a = 3211 - 6.45 * a
```

Now we can solve for a:

```
3101 - 6.5 * a - 3211 + 6.45 * a = 0
-110 -0.05 * a = 0
-110 = 0.05 * a
-2200 = a
```

Given this a we can solve for b using either of the original two equations:

```
3101 - 6.5  * a = b 
3101 - 6.5 * -2200 = b
3101 + 14300 = b
17401 = b
b = 17401
```

So for X we have this formula:

```
X2 = -2200 * X1 + 17401
```

Let's try X1 = 6.5 and X1 = 6.45:

```
X2 = -2200 * 6.5 + 17401
X2 = -14300 + 17401
X2 = 3101

X2 = -2200 * 6.45 + 17401
X2 = -14190 + 17401
X2 = 3211
```

Doing the exact same math for Y gives me that the relationship follows this formula:

```
Y2 = Y1 * A + B
3441 = 2 * A + B                 3414 = 2.37 * A + B
3441 - 2 * A = B                 3414 - 2.37 * A = B
3441 - 2 * A = 3414 - 2.37 * A
3441 - 2 * A - 3414 + 2.37 * A = 0
27 + 0.37 * A = 0
     0.37 * A = -27
     0.37 * A = -27
            A = -72.973

3441 = 2 * A + B
3441 = 2 * -72.973 + B
3441 - 2 * -72.973 = B
3441 + 145.946 = B
3586.946 = B
B = 3586.946
```

Which gives:

```
Y2 = Y1 * -72.973 + 3586.946
```

Let's test:

```
Y2 = 2 * -72.973 + 3586.946
Y2 = -145.946 + 3586.946
Y2 = 3441

Y2 = 2.37 * -72.973 + 3586.946
Y2 = -172.946 + 3586.946
Y2 = 3414
```

---

Your translation formulas are this:

```
X2 = X1 * -2200  + 17401
Y2 = Y1 * 72.973 + 3586.946
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account rotations of the coordinate system. Then again, OP hasn't said if they are allowed.

Comment: @Lasse thanks for this, the explanation is very much appreciated. Just what i was looking for. @ cfh I didnt need to rotate or scale anything, I just needed to find the relationship between those two numbers so I could calculate future numbers of the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is called linear interpolation, rule of three, etc